# Why did Ali (a.s) order to be buried in secret?

Tags: history, ali

It is said that Ali (a.s) asked his friends and family to bury him secretly. His burial  was revealed only later during the Abbasid caliphate by Imam Ja'far al-Sadiq (a.s), his descendant and the sixth Shia Imam.

- **Why did he order to be buried in secret?**

**Ref:**

*[Al-Shaykh Al-Mufid (1986). Kitab Al-Irshad: The Book of Guidance into the Lives of the Twelve Imams. Routledge Kegan & Paul. ISBN 978-0-7103-0151-2.](http://books.google.com/books/about/The_book_of_guidance_into_the_lives_of_t.html?id=NVnYAAAAMAAJ)*

Comment: According to whom?

Answer (score 2):

That was because of the Khawarij. They hated Ali (a.s.), they believed him to be a Kafir, they betrayed him in the battle of Siffin, they fought against him in the battle of Nahrwan and one of them (Ibn Muljim) finally killed him.
But that was not enough for them. Ali knew that the Khawarij would desecrate his grave, if they knew where it was located.

After a few hundred years, in the time of Imam Ja'far Sadiq (a.s.), the Khawaraij became extinct, so that there was no threat anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Although *Khawarij* hated Imam Ali (a.s.), but he  buried in secret mainly because of *bani umayyah*. The reason for this claim is that:

1-*bani umayyah* also hated Imam Ali (a.s.)
2- After *bani umayyah* overthrew,  the burial place revealed. in that time *Khawarij* were not completely exterminated.
  *Sheikh Mofid* claims this fact in Al-Ershad, too. You know Farsi, so I give [this link](http://www.ahlebayt.porsemani.ir/content/%D8%A2%D9%8A%D8%A7-%D9%82%D8%A8%D8%B1-%D8%AD%D8%B6%D8%B1%D8%AA-%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%8A%D8%B9-%D9%85%D8%AE%D9%81%D9%8A-%D8%A8%D9%88%D8%AF%D9%87-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%9F) for you and others who know Farsi.

Comment: I de facto appreciate you short informative answer, particularly its helpful source as you linked it. God bless you.

Comment: Cursing on Ali as a liar , kafir etc. was pretty common in bani Umayyad era and was introduced by Muawiya .